# Using doppler radar to detect bullets

Tags: arduino, radar

I'am wondering if it is possible to use an cheap doppler radar module from ebay (like HB100) to detect a bullet and calculate the entry hole on the target.
We are shooting with 4,5mm (.177) match diabolo pellets which have a velocity of ~170m/s.
The idea is to build a cheap device to detect your shooting results in combination with an Arduino. There are commercial solutions available but they are very expensive and other techniques involving infrared or microphones seems be fragile and complicated to implement.
While I'am experienced in programming I have no idea about electronics.
Is it possible to implement something like this with these cheap modules?

Comment: Radar uses sound. At a pellet speed of 170m/s your pellets are travelling approximately half the speed of sound. You'll have very poor resolution if it works at all. 
You'll have much more success with an optical setup, perhaps an IR or Laser grid with photo-diodes

Comment: Radar doesn't use sound!

Comment: RADAR = [RAdio Detection And Ranging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar). You're thinking of SONAR maybe, or the Doppler effect on sound.

Answer (score 2):

The [HB100](http://www.limpkin.fr/public/HB100/HB100_Microwave_Sensor_Module_Datasheet.pdf) is an X-band doppler motion detector that uses pulses at a few kHz repetition rate. You might be able to detect the speed of the projectile (about 10.7kHz from the IF output at very low amplitude) but it would be non-trivial to do so. If you're shooting from ~25m then the time available is enough to get a few hundred pings (only the nearest ones may be distinguishable from noise with such a small projectile, and of course there is a cosine error term with any doppler).

It's useless for measuring impact position. Personally I would tend to something more along the lines of gluing a piezo element or accelerometer to the back of a metal plate that is the exact size of the target area. Keep in mind that if someone actually fires a real firearm at the target, the accelerometer in particular may not survive.

Comment: I noticed the datasheet specs noise floor from 10 ~ 100Hz. Is it reasonable that there will be an IF ouput signal in the 10kHz range? I couldn't really find any mention of IF bandwidth or similar.

Comment: @jippie No idea if there is any significant kHz filtering in there or not. It's not expected to find objects whizzing around at ~600km/h when you're looking for shoppers (even at Christmas rush), but maybe there's no need to filter it out either. As you say, no mention of bandwidth. They probably filter out the ~10GHz, but that's a long ways (6 orders of magnitude) from 10kHz.